# React delete active class after second click

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in React. I needed active class that can be active only on one element at time and it's work, but if I click one of the element, active class is constantly active on one of them. I need to switch class to inactive, if i click element already active or even better, after click an active element or outside of the elements.

**MenuDish.js**

```
const MenuDish = props =>{
 
  const clickHandler = (keyID) => {
    props.onChange(keyID); 
  }
    return (
        <Card className={"menu-dish no-paddings " + (props.disabled === props.id ? "active-card" : "inactive-card")} >
            <Button className={"dish-img-button shadow-none border-none " } onClick={(e) => clickHandler(props.id, e)}>
              <Image fluid src={props.dishImage} className={"dish-image-width " + (props.disabled === props.id ? "active-card-image" :  "inactive-card-image") }>                  
              </Image>
              <div className={"image-blur "+ (props.disabled === props.id ? "active-card-blur" : "inactive-card-blur")}></div> 
            </Button>
        </Card>
    )
    
}
```

**MenuDishes.js**

```
const MenuDishes = (props) =>{
    const [active, setActive] = useState();

    function activeButton(value){
        setActive(value)
    }
    
   return (
        props.dishes.map((item) =>(
            <MenuDish dish={item.dish_name} price={item.dish_cost} dishImage={item.dish_img_link} key={item.id} ingredients={item.dish_ingredient_list} description={item.dish_description} category={item.dish_category} isVege={""+ item.dish_is_vege} spiciness={item.dish_spiciness} onChange={activeButton} disabled={active} id={item.id}/>
        ))    
    );
```

Comment: Add the code, where you are using the `MenuDish`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a state in parent component to maintain the active id.
- Based on that state change the active class

**Parent**

```
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);

const onChange = (id) => {
  setSelectedId(id === selectedId ? null : id); //To close the Menu if its already opened
};

<MenuDish onChange={onChange} selectedId={selectedId} />;
```

**MenuDish**

```
const MenuDish = (props) =>{
 
  const clickHandler = (keyID) => {
    props.onChange(keyID); 
  }
    return (
        <Card className={"menu-dish no-paddings " + (props.selectedId === props.id ? "active-card" : "inactive-card")} >
            <Button className={"dish-img-button shadow-none border-none " } onClick={(e) => clickHandler(props.id, e)}>
              <Image fluid src={props.dishImage} className={"dish-image-width " + (props.selectedId === props.id ? "active-card-image" :  "inactive-card-image") }>                  
              </Image>
              <div className={"image-blur "+ (props.selectedId === props.id ? "active-card-blur" : "inactive-card-blur")}></div> 
            </Button>
        </Card>
    )
    
}
```

...

```
props.selectedId === props.id ? "active-class"
```

Comment: I tried this and works exactly the same

Comment: Could you provide a [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/)?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-violet-d10fd?file=/src/App.js

In my project i getting data from firebase, so in codebox i create array with elements. Normally I don't have this

Comment: I have updated the `onChange` in parent, it will now close the menu if its already opened

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-northcutt-b3c20?file=/src/MenuDishes.js:6387-6518  now it doesn't works at all

Comment: my bad, updated the answer.https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-bogdan-97kso?file=/src/MenuDish.js